# display data from another table when select option is being selected using js?

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to generate data from select box, I made a simple query to database where it will generate list of categories in selection box. Now my problem is that, how do i get data from another table that will promptly display if the selectbox is being selected. I believe there is a javascript related to this for much easier way. Can someone please tell me, or illustrate how should it be done?

```
<select name="categoryID" id="" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="" default>SELECT</option>
            <?php 
              $select = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM category");
              while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
                $showlumber = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM inventorylumber WHERE categoryID = '$row[categoryID]'");
                $rowLumber = $showlumber->fetch_assoc();
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['categoryID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['categoryName']; ?>                  
            </option>

            <?php } ?>

          </select>
          </div>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>2 x 2</th>
                <th><?php echo $rowLumber['2x2x6']; ?>Pcs</th>
                <th><?php echo $rowLumber['2x2x8']; ?>Pcs</th>
                <th><?php echo $rowLumber['2x2x10']; ?>Pcs</th>
                <th><?php echo $rowLumber['2x2x12']; ?>Pcs</th>
                <th><?php echo $rowLumber['2x2x14']; ?>Pcs</th>
                <th><?php echo $rowLumber['2x2x16']; ?>Pcs</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
```

Comment: PHP way take is action from a POST(ajax your way, sending form ...) or GET (ajax, refresh page, pass args to url).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like that.